Methods to test independence in a non parametric setting
I am using random forest as my regression model and have the following data where X is a high dimensional data set in a simplex form.
I have tried using permutation and the following code:
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X = pd.read_csv("X_p.csv", delimiter=",", engine="c", index_col=0, low_memory=False)
Y = pd.read_csv("Y_p.csv", delimiter=",", engine="c", low_memory=False)

X = X.iloc[:, 1:]
Y = Y.iloc[:, 1:]

Y = Y['0'].values.ravel()

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,min_samples_split=5,max_depth=50, random_state=42)


original_mse = mean_squared_error(Y_train, rf_model.fit(X_train, Y_train).predict(X_train))

permuted_mse = []
for _ in range(10):  # Number of permutations
    permuted_Y = np.random.permutation(Y_train)
    permuted_mse.append(mean_squared_error(permuted_Y, rf_model.fit(X_train, permuted_Y).predict(X_train)))

# Step 6: Significance Testing based on MSE
p_value_mse = np.sum(permuted_mse > original_mse) / (len(permuted_mse)+1)

# Print results
print("Original MSE:", original_mse)
print("Permutation test p-value based on MSE:", p_value_mse)

output:
Original MSE: 2.2922379491349436
Permutation test p-value based on MSE: 0.9090909090909091

Process finished with exit code 0

Just running 10 permutations the code takes quite a long time and it always returns a very high p value (bassicly all permuted mse's are larger than the initial one) what is my mistake? I have tried to modify my random forest parameters but nothings seems to help.

What is the null hypothesis you are trying to test? If it is not obvious, can you explain why the training MSE of a regressor trained on the data is an appropriate statistic for detecting departure from that null hypothesis?

I've added a response about the p-value aspect of the code. I don't have anything to suggest for making the training of the random forest model faster. (In the time between posting this question and now, you might have had time for many permutations, so the speed might not be a problem!) You might want to open a new question about that since this question (and answer) is mostly about the permutation test, and S.O. is better suited to one specific question at a time. You can also post on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) about other tests that might be faster.


I guess the idea behind using mse is to evaluate that our initial mse should be lower than a randomly permuted vision of the data

That highlights the problem with the implementation of the permutation test: your alternative hypothesis is that the observed MSE is lower than if Y were independent of X. In other words, a lower MSE is "more extreme" than one would expect to get by chance under the null hypothesis. So the last step should be:
p_value_mse = (np.sum(permuted_mse <= original_mse) + 1) / (len(permuted_mse)+1)

This makes three changes to the above code:

Use < instead of > to correspond with the alternative hypothesis being tested.
Use <= instead of < because elements of the null distribution equal to your observed statistic would also be considered "extreme".
Add +1 in the numerator as well as the denominator (reference). These +1s are commonly interpreted as including the original observation in the permutation distribution, which gives an intuitive reason for including them in both the numerator and denominator. See 1 for more information, though: there is a case to be made for  this being an approximation to a (long-run) "exact" p-value (despite the use of randomization).

You might also read the SciPy tutorial about Resampling and Monte Carlo Methods if you're unfamiliar with the topic of permutation tests.
